# How are ternary expressions in Java evaluated?

Tags: java, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I have followed the tutorial provided [here](http://www.wideskills.com/java-tutorial/java-operators-tutorial) and in the line:

```
boolean t1 = false?false:true?false:true?false:true;
```

the final value of `t1` is false. But I've evaluated it as true.
The first false gives true and that true gives false, which further finally gives true,
am I right? No, I am wrong.
Could you please tell me how ternary expressions are evaluated in Java?

Comment: your code can be simplified to `boolean t1 = !false && (true ? false : true ? false : true);` which is always `false`.

Comment: try to use brackets/parenthesis to make your life easier on this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the compiler finds a `?` character, it looks for a corresponding `:`. The expression before the `?` is the first operand of the ternary conditional operator, which represents the condition.

The expression between the `?` and the `:` is the second operand of the operator, whose value is returned if the condition is true.

The expression after the `:` is the third operand of the operator, whose value is returned if the condition is false.

```
boolean t1 = false   ? false    :    true?false:true?false:true;

             first     second        third
             operand   operand       operand
```

Since first operand is false, the result is the value of the third operand `true?false:true?false:true`, so let's evaluate it:

```
true    ?   false    : true?false:true;

first       second     third
operand     operand    operand
```

Since first operand is true, the result is the value of the second operand - `false`.

BTW, the value of the third operand `true?false:true` is also `false`, so `x?false:true?false:true` returns false regardless of the value of `x`.

Answer (score 4):

We can regroup these operations according to associativity rules.

```
boolean t1 = (false ? false : (true ? false : (true ? false : true)));
                  |                      |               | 
                  |                      |               1
                  |                      2
                  3
```

In theory, this is what should happen

1. Exp 1 is evaluated first and is evaluated as `false`.
2. Exp 2 is now: `true? false : false` so the final output is `false`.
3. Exp 3 now becomes `false ? false : false`, which is `false`.

---

Now, to get technical, this is what actually happens:

1. Exp 3 is `false ? (don't care) : (...)` -> the inner expression containing Exp 2 and Exp 1 need to be evaluated.
2. Exp 2 is `true: false, (don't care)` Since we've already determined the value of Exp 2, Exp 1 no longer needs to be evaluated.
3. Exp 3 is now reevaluated to be `false ? (don't care) : false` and so the final answer is `false`.

Comment: Actually what you denoted at "Exp 1" is never evaluated at all. It's dead code.

Comment: @Eran I was trying not to get too technical for a java beginner. But I suppose it is important to mention. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

The Pseudocode below shows how the expression is evaluated:

```
boolean t1 = false?false:true?false:true?false:true              
           = true && (true ? false : true ? false : true)
           = true && false
           = false
```

Another way to look at it:

```
boolean t1 = false?false:true?false:true?false:true;
```

can be simplified to:

```
boolean t1 = !false && (true ? false : true ? false : true);
```

then simplified to:

```
boolean t1 = true && (true ? false : true ? false : true);
```

then simplified to:

```
boolean t1 = true && false;
```

which eventually results in `false`;